# Prevent Gmail login to change my Chrome profile

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, bookmarks

I have multiple gmail accounts.  My issue is that when I login into a gmail account it switches my Chrome profile to match that gmail account.  This makes me lose all my bookmarks, etc.  This already happened once when, without my knowledge, I deleted my old profile and lost all my bookmarks, etc.  I would like to find one of two solutions:

1. Can I disable Chrome profile complete?  I found some articles on the web that provide a way to do this by going to chrome/flags, but I can't find the setting that they mentioned in that article.
2. I don't want the Chrome profile to change when I log into a different GMAIL account.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to use a single Chrome profile, why are you logging into your Google account within Chrome, why not just have an single offline profile? If you want profile synchronization, you could simply use a single Google account for that purpose, allowing you to use your other Google profiles within the normal Google interfaces.  Google Chrome is designed, so if you logged into an account, you will switch profiles.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you were able to find the fix, as there are no further responses to this thread.
For anybody who lands here ( courtesy : Google), here is a link with screenshot that helped me.

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/remove-a-google-account-from-chrome/

Comment: It should not be necessary to follow a link to get the answer here. Please edit your answer to fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] and include the image that helped you, in your answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1130534)

Comment: Chrome - Settings - You and Google - Sync and Google services - Allow chrome sign in - disable